# How can I code a matrix within a matrix using a loop?

Tags: python, numpy

So I have this 3x3 G matrix (not shown here, it's irrelevant to my problem) that I created using the two variables u (a vector, x - y) and the scalar k. x_j = (x_1 (j), x_2 (j), x_3 (j)) and  y_j = (y_1 (j), y_2 (j), y_3 (j)). alpha_j is a 3x3 matrix. The A matrix is block diagonal matrix of size 3nx3n. I am having trouble with the W matrix. How do I code a matrix of size 3nx3n, where the (i,j)th block is the 3x3 matrix given by alpha_i*G_[ij]*alpha_j?? I am lost.

My alpha_j matrix also seems to be having some trouble. The loop keeps throwing me the error, "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars." pls help :/

```
def W(x, y, k, alpha, A):
    u = x - y
    n = x.shape[0]
    W = np.zeros((3*n, 3*n))

    for i in range(0, n-1):
        for j in range(0, n-1):
                #u = -np.array([[x[i,0] - x[j,0]], [x[i,1] -               x[j,1]], [0]]) ??
                W[i][j] = (alpha_j(alpha, A) * G(u, k) * alpha_j(alpha, A))
        W[i][i] = np.zeros((n, n))

    return W

def alpha_j(a, A):
    alph = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],complex)
    rho = np.random.rand(3,1)
    for i in range(0, 2):
        for j in range(0, 2):
            alph[i][j] = (rho[i] * a * A[i][j])
    return alph

#-------------------------------------------------------------------

x1 = np.array([[1], [2], [0]])
y1 = np.array([[4], [5], [0]])

# SYSTEM PARAMETERS

# incoming Wave angle
theta = 0 # can range from [0, 2pi)

# susceptibility
chi = 10 + 1j

# wavelength
lam = 0.5 # microns (values between .4-.7)

# frequency
k = (2 * np.pi)/lam # 1/microns

# volume
V_0 = (0.05)**3 # microns^3

# incoming wave vector
K = k * np.array([[0], [np.sin(theta)], [np.cos(theta)]])

# polarization vector
vecinc = np.array([[1], [0], [0]]) # (can choose any vector perpendicular to K)

# for the fixed alpha case
alpha = (V_0 * 3 * chi)/(chi + 3)

# 3 x 3 matrix
A = np.matlib.identity(3) # could be any symmetric matrix, 


#-------------------------------------------------------------------

# TEST FUNCTIONS

test = G((x1-y1), k)
print(test)

w = W(x1, y1, k, alpha, A)
print(w)
```

Sometimes my W loops throws me the error, "can't set an array element with a sequence." But I need to set each array element in this arbitrary matrix W to the 3x3 matrix created by multiplying alpha by G...

Comment: Hi @Becs! First, could you create a _minimal_ example that reproduces your problem? (This might even help you answer your own question.) Second, it would help readability if you could surround the inline code with backticks `so it looks like this`. Third, including some minimal sample input data and desired output might help both you and potential responders. Fourth, and finally, what have you tried so far to get rid of these errors?

Comment: hey! somebody ended up pointing me in the right direction but I will keep your tips in mind, thank you :)

Comment: The `G` 'matrix' is relevant to the problem.  We can't run your code without it, and thus cannot reproduce your error.  But you use `G` as though it were a function, not a matrix.

Comment: Your error is the result of making `A` a `np.matrix` and indexing with `[i][j]` style instead of `[i,j]`.  Correcting those, we get another error - `setting element with sequence`.  That's because `W` is initialed as 2d, when it should be 4d.

Comment: Why do you use: `range(0, n-1)`.  Don't you want to iterate over `n` values?

Comment: @hpaulji G is a complicated function that involves partial derivatives and norms that I have set to return a complex 3x3 matrix. I just thought it would be easier to just create a random 3x3 in this case. I ended up correcting the [i,j], thank you! Should I use n? I though python's indexing started at 0? So if I wanted to iterate to the end of a list of 5 you would have to tell it from 0 to 4 (as that is 5 elements)? Is this wrong

Comment: Have you looked at `list(range(0,4))`? You didn't need to give the real `G`; just something that lets us test the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your question of how to create a new array with a block for each element, the following should do the trick:

```py
G = np.random.random([3,3])
result = np.zeros([9,9])
num_blocks = 3
a = np.random.random([3,3])
b = np.random.random([3,3])
for i in range(G.shape[0]):
    for j in range(G.shape[1]):
        block_result = a*G[i,j]*b
        for k in range(num_blocks):
            for l in range(num_blocks):
                result[3*i + k, 3*j + l] = block_result[i, j]
```

You should be able to generalize from there. I hope I've understood correctly.

EDIT: It looks like I haven't understood correctly. I'm leaving it in hopes it spurs you to an answer. The general idea is to generate ranges of indices to operate on, and then just operate on them directly. Slicing might be helpful, too.

Ah, you asked how to create a diagonal filled with blocks. In that case:

```py
num_diagonal_blocks = 3 # for example

for block_dim in range(num_diagonal_blocks)
    # do your block calculation...
    for k in range(G.shape[0]):
        for l in range(G.shape[1]):
            result[3*block_dim + k, 3*block_dim + l] = # assign to element of block
```

I think that's nearly it.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's very helpful. I'm not quite sure I understand the line "result[3*i + k, 3*j + l]" yet. How would I make the diagonal, block_result[i, i], equal to a 3x3 matrix of zeros?

Comment: Can you mark my answer as the correct one, then? (And/or upvote it?) Thanks!